# Using a Stream builder inside a Future builder (Flutter with Firestore)

Tags: flutter

I want to use a stream to get data from a Firestore document, but getting the stream involves reading from Firestore first. This means that it is async, and therefore returns a `Future<Stream>`:

```
Future<Stream<WeekData>?> thisWeekStream(DateTime weekStartDate) async {
  // A few steps here involving reading from Firestore to find the appropriate document
  // (i.e. async functions)

  return weekDataCollection.doc(doc.id).snapshots().map((snapshot) =>
    WeekData.fromJson(doc.id, snapshot.data() as Map<String, Object?>));
  }
}
```

So for my screen, I am using a `FutureBuilder` with a `StreamBuilder` inside it:

```
FutureBuilder<Stream<WeekData>?>(
        // Firstly, get the Future of Stream<WeekData>
        future: _weekDataDatabase.thisWeekStream(DateTime.now().getWeekStart()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Error in FutureBuilder');
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const LoadingWidget(); // Loading the Future
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // Once Future is completed and returns Stream<WeekData>, build UI using stream
            return StreamBuilder<WeekData>(builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                WeekData weekData = snapshot.data!;
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(weekData.weekStartDate.toString()),
                    Text(weekData.nSessionsList.toString()),
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const LoadingWidget(); // Loading the Stream
              } else {
                return const Text('Error in stream');
              }
            });
          } else {
            return const LoadingWidget();
          }
        },
      ),
```

But it's not working: on the screen, I get the text widget "Error in stream" and when I looked inside in the debug console, `ConnectionState` for the stream appeared to be `ConnectionState.none`. I can't figure out why the stream is returning nothing.

Comment: no need to use outer `FutureBuilder` - just use `StreamBuilder` with a stream coming from `async*` generator - more here: [Creating a stream from scratch](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch)

Comment: alternatively you can also use `StreamCompleter` (or even `StreamController`)

Comment: @pskink can you explain further? How do I exactly use my stream directly in a StreamBuilder? My `thisWeekStream` returns a `Future<Stream<WeekData>>` so I can't pass it to the stream property.

Comment: I did some googling about async generators and found [this article](https://medium.com/@dumazy/create-a-stream-that-requires-a-future-in-dart-692f6f089a7e) which I think is exactly what @pskink was talking about, and it has solved my problem!

Comment: and if you dont like `async*` generators and `yield*` statements you can always use "normal" `async` function and calling `StreamCompleter.setSourceStream`